# How can I specify system properties in Tomcat configuration on startup?

Tags: tomcat, properties, system-properties, context.xml

I understand that I can specify system properties to Tomcat by passing arguments with the -D parameter, for example "**-Dmy.prop=value**".

I am wondering if there is a cleaner way of doing this by specifying the property values in the context.xml file or some other tomcat configuration file. I would like to do this because, first, it is easier to keep track of my properties, and second, I have multiple contexts running and I don't know how I would specify context-specific properties through the -D parameter.

I am using Tomcat version 5.5.

Comment: append "property=value" as pure text to catalina.properties. (in linux it's in /etc/tomcat )

Answer (score 15, accepted):

(Update: If I could delete this answer I would, although since it's accepted, I can't. I'm updating the description to provide better guidance and discourage folks from using the poor practice I outlined in the original answer).

You can specify these parameters via context or environment parameters, such as in context.xml.  See the sections titled "Context Parameters" and "Environment Entries" on this page:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html

As @netjeff points out, these values will be available via the Context.lookup(String) method and not as System parameters.

Another way to do specify these values is to define variables inside of the web.xml file of the web application you're deploying (see below). As @Roberto Lo Giacco points out, this is generally considered a poor practice since a deployed artifact should not be environment specific. However, below is the configuration snippet if you really want to do this:

```xml
<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>SMTP_PASSWORD</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>abc123ftw</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

Comment: I couldn't get my web.xml to validate using the above. Switching the order of the env-entry-value and env-entry-type entries worked, though.

Comment: Okay, the DTD or XSD probably specifies a precise order for those elements. I've updated my answer accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: FYI, as noted in my answer below, the <env-entry> values will not appear in System.getProperty().

Comment: Please do NOT apply this advice to the web.xml file: your deployable will be environment specific and, as such, you are realizing an anti-pattern. Context and environment parameters are a good place for these settings.

Comment: This is great if you like hard-coding things that change in every environment like your logging directory. ;-) It also doesn't answer the question as it was asked.

Answer (score 29):

*cliff.meyers*'s original answer that suggested using `<env-entry>` will not help when using only System.getProperty()

According to the Tomcat 6.0 docs [`<env-entry>` is for JNDI](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html).  So that means it won't have any effect on `System.getProperty()`.

With the `<env-entry>` from *cliff.meyers*'s example, the following code

```java
System.getProperty("SMTP_PASSWORD");
```

will return null, not the value "abc123ftw".

According to the Tomcat 6 docs, to use `<env-entry>` you'd have to write code like this to use `<env-entry>`:

```java
// Obtain our environment naming context
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");

// Look up our data source
String s = (String)envCtx.lookup("SMTP_PASSWORD");
```

Caveat:  I have not actually tried the example above.  But I **have** tried `<env-entry>` with System.getProperty(), and that definitely does not work.

Comment: When he asked for a cleaner way of doing it, I interpreted that to mean suggestions as to not using System properties as well.  I did not intend my answer to work with:

    System.getProperty("SMTP_PASSWORD")

Comment: Yes, I see now what you were aiming for.  In that case, my answer "clarifies" that if Markus were to use <env-entry> in context.xml, then he would have to use the slightly more complicated Context API (as in my example), rather than one-liner System.getProperty().  I hope Markus found something that worked for his needs.

Answer (score 13):

Generally you shouldn't rely on system properties to configure a webapp - they may be used to configure the container (e.g. Tomcat) but not an application running inside tomcat.

cliff.meyers has already mentioned the way you should rather use for your webapplication. That's the standard way, that also fits your question of being configurable through context.xml or server.xml means.

That said, should you really need system properties or other jvm options (like max memory settings) in tomcat, you should create a file named "bin/setenv.sh" or "bin/setenv.bat". These files do not exist in the standard archive that you download, but if they are present, the content is executed during startup (if you start tomcat via startup.sh/startup.bat). This is a nice way to separate your own settings from the standard tomcat settings and makes updates so much easier. No need to tweak startup.sh or catalina.sh.

(If you execute tomcat as windows servive, you usually use tomcat5w.exe, tomcat6w.exe etc. to configure the registry settings for the service.)

EDIT: Also, another possibility is to go for [JNDI Resources](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html).

Answer (score 13):

It's also possible letting a ServletContextListener set the System properties:

```java
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.servlet.*;

public class SystemPropertiesHelper implements
        javax.servlet.ServletContextListener {
    private ServletContext context = null;

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        context = event.getServletContext();
        Enumeration<String> params = context.getInitParameterNames();

        while (params.hasMoreElements()) {
          String param = (String) params.nextElement();
          String value = 
            context.getInitParameter(param);
          if (param.startsWith("customPrefix.")) {
              System.setProperty(param, value);
          }
        }
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
    }
}
```

And then put this into your web.xml (should be possible for context.xml too)

```xml
<context-param>
        <param-name>customPrefix.property</param-name>
        <param-value>value</param-value>
        <param-type>java.lang.String</param-type>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>servletUtils.SystemPropertiesHelper</listener-class>    
</listener>
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

An alternative to setting the system property on tomcat configuration is to use CATALINA_OPTS environment variable

Answer (score 6):

This question is addressed in the Apache wiki.

Question: "Can I set Java system properties differently for each webapp?"

Answer: No. If you can edit Tomcat's startup scripts (or better create a setenv.sh file), you can add "-D" options to Java. But there is no way in Java to have different values of system properties for different classes in the same JVM.  There are some other methods available, like using ServletContext.getContextPath() to get the context name of your web application and locate some resources accordingly, or to define  elements in WEB-INF/web.xml file of your web application and then set the values for them in Tomcat context file (META-INF/context.xml). See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html .

http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#Can_I_set_Java_system_properties_differently_for_each_webapp.3F

Answer (score 4):

You could add necessary properties to `catalina.properties` file in `<tomcat installation directory>/conf` directory.

Reference: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/index.html

> All system properties are available including those set using the -D
>   syntax, those automatically made available by the JVM and those
>   configured in the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define an environment variable in your context base on documentation you shod define them as below

```
<Context ...>
  ...
  <Environment name="maxExemptions" value="10"
         type="java.lang.Integer" override="false"/>
  ...
</Context>
```

Also use them as below:

```
((Context)new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env")).lookup("maxExemptions")
```

You should get `10` as output.