# Setting java system properties to a java application

Tags: java, tomcat, properties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I specify system properties in Tomcat configuration on startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372686/how-can-i-specify-system-properties-in-tomcat-configuration-on-startup)

What i'm trying to do, eventually, is to start TOMCAT with certain java system properties set (in this case jmx setup):

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9898 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false`
```

)

Problem is I don't think i'm doing it right.
What I'm doing is, in the command prompt window (Working in Vista 64, BTW) I use:

```
set CATALINA_OPTS=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote...
set JAVA_OPTS=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote...
tomcat6.exe
```

This doesn't seem to work since tomcat6 is not behaving as if the properties were set.
To test this I used the example Notepad.Jar that comes with the java jdk.
Tried to run it the same way:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote...
java -jar Notepad.jar
```

which didn't work, but this did work:

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote .... -jar Notepad.jar
```

Since the last attempt did work I concluded that the JAVA/CATALINA_OPTS setup is incorrect.

Could someone point out what i'm doing wrong? I hope I was clear enough.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the supplied startup.bat and catalina.bat files instead of calling tonmcat.exe directly. This has always worked for me...

Comment: Tnx. I don't have these batch files, are they installed separately?
I'm using Tomcat 6.0, perhaps it's different here?

Comment: I downloaded tomcat in a different package and got those batch files. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, these variables are used by the tomcat startup script and not by Java directly. Here's a link that might help you:

[CATALINA_OPTS v JAVA_OPTS - What is the difference?](http://www.wellho.net/mouth/2163_CATALINA-OPTS-v-JAVA-OPTS-What-is-the-difference-.html)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this by running the server from bootstrap.jar in a similiar manner to the way I started notepad.jar.

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9898 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -jar bootstrap.jar
```

Apparently catalina.bat and startup.bat do no exists in tomcat6.0.
I haven't found proper documentation for the changes from 5.5 to 6.0 which describe the removal of these startup batch files, which is a shame because i'm still not sure i'm doing it the correct way. 
Although it works which is, I guess, a good start.

Answer (score 0):

try;

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote...
java %JAVA_OPTS% -jar Notepad.jar
```

take note of **%JAVA_OPTS%**