# which file in tomcat 7.0.22 is equivalent to properties-service.xml of jboss?

Tags: tomcat7

which file in tomcat7.0.22 is equivalent to properties-service.xml of jboss 6.0? or where I can  mention path/URL of external proerties file in tomcat7.0.22. Please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Its not exist because properties-service.xml is JBoss specific file. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372686/how-can-i-specify-system-properties-in-tomcat-configuration-on-startup) is more standard way to set properties for the web applications.