# Cloudbees, Tomcat, and Spring: "Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'"

Tags: spring, tomcat, cloudbees

I'm trying to deploy my Spring MVC webapp (Hibernate and JPA) to a Tomcat 7 ClickStack in Cloudbees, but cannot seem to configure the database connection properly. I've tried following multiple tutorials (which offer many solutions), none of which have worked. If someone could take a look at my config files below and let me know if they see anything wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

The error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
```

First, I bound my database to my app using the cloudbees cli so that I don't have to declare it in cloudbees-web.xml:

```
bees app:bind -a myapp/app -db mydatabase
    application - myapp/app bound to cb-db:myapp/mydatabase as mydatabase
```

(I have also tried unbinding the database and defining it in cloudbees-web.xml and also in context.xml without success)

**spring-data.xml:**

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="datasource" jndi-name="jdbc/mydatabase"
                 lookup-on-startup="false" proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource"
                 cache="true" resource-ref="true"  />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="hibernate-jpa"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
            <property name="showSql" value="false"/>
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**web.xml:**

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/mydatabase</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

I have removed all references to connectors from my Maven files and all jars from the `lib` folder. Searching for the error message shows that it usually has to do with the driver not being found... but since the database is supplied by the container, why do I have to worry about that?

### -- EDIT: Working META-INF/context.xml file --

Note that the com.cloudbees.jdbc.Driver referenced in a lot of the docs didn't work (threw a classnotfound exception), so I had to package the mysql-connector-java.jar file in the lib folder. Also, for now I just hardcoded the url, username, and password instead of setting it up to use the system properties.

```
<Context>
<Loader delegate="true"/>
<Resource
        name="jdbc/mydatabase"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="5"
        maxIdle="2"
        username="USERNAME"
        maxWait="5000"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        password="PASSWORD"
        url="jdbc:mysql://MY_EC2_DB_URL:3306/mydatabase"/>
</Context>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately at this point in time, the JNDI DB setup is not done for you in the tomcat7 stack.

When you bind the database to your app - it injects some system properties:

```
MYSQL_PASSWORD_MYDB 
MYSQL_URL_MYDB
MYSQL_USERNAME_MYDB
```

(MYDB as it is the name of your db resource). You can then refer to them in your code/config. 
For tomcat 7, you can put in /META-INF/context.xml into your app which will set up the JNDI data source (see http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html)

Comment: Thanks, setting it up in the context.xml worked (although I couldn't find a reference to how to put system properties into the file). For anyone reading this in the future, I added my context.xml resource configuration to the ticket.

Comment: great andy - I am not sure if tomcat supports system properties in the context - I suspect they do (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372686/how-can-i-specify-system-properties-in-tomcat-configuration-on-startup - does that make any sense).

Comment: Hi ! Is there any news about the JNDI DB setup for the Tomcat7 stack ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and finally managed to "properly" configure the datasource !

I'm using a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer as follows :

```
<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
   <property name="showSql" value="false" />
   <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
   <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
</bean>

<context:property-placeholder system-properties-mode="FALLBACK" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
   <property name="driverClassName" value="${dt4j.driver}" />
   <property name="url" value="${dt4j.url}" />
   <property name="username" value="${dt4j.username}" />
   <property name="password" value="${dt4j.password}" />
</bean>
```

"FALLBACK" indicates placeholders should be resolved against any local properties and then against system properties.

Finally, I just need to add system properties (-Dprop=value) or add them in the Cloudbees deployer plugin to make it work.
There must be a better way but the main goal is achieved : the data source configuration is not hardcoded in the project !