# How to store my symmetric key in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, security, encryption, cryptography

I would like to store encrypted data in my db as well as its signature so that I could read it back at another time. How do I store the symmetric key used for encryption safely?

Comment: Its signature will not let decrypt the date. You are supposed to use secret key to decrypt data if you are using symmetric encryption. Otherwise you may want to use asymmetric encryption and store open key in db to decrypt data

Comment: Sorry, should have worded things better. I thought it would be implied that the signature is to ensure the integrity of the data. Edit: About your second line: how do I store the sk then?

Answer (score 1):

Store it on the file system and never version track it!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer to my question here: [Where do you store your secret key in a Java Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13991100/where-do-you-store-your-secret-key-in-a-java-web-application)

Please let me know if there's a better way of doing things.

TLDR: Store it on the file system.