# How to use a System.getProperty() for an application running on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I am trying to set a system property and retrieve it in my Servlet.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("name"));
    }
```

I placed this: `-Dname=rickesh` in CATALINA_OPTS but running the code returns `null`. I have no idea as to how I can pass parameters to Tomcat at runtime and use it via `System.getProperty(String)`. A [Google Search](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=pass%20runtime%20parameter%20to%20tomcat&aq=f&oq=pass%20runtime%20parameter%20to%20tomcat&aqs=chrome.0.64.1037j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to do the same suggests to do a JNDI or set in CATALINA_OPTS, but no example on how to set either.

Please advice.

Comment: Where are you setting your CATALINA_OPTS? And what does it look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372686/how-can-i-specify-system-properties-in-tomcat-configuration-on-startup

Comment: environment variable... :|
i hope that's how it is done

Comment: @Nilsh CATALINA_OPTS -Dname=rickesh


in environment variables

Comment: Which OS? I'm guessing the env variable isn't set properly.

Comment: OS being used is Windows XP.

Answer (score 8):

After some hit and trial, placed `name=rickesh` in `catalina.properties` present in `C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\conf`. Works fine.