# Setting up System Properties in Apache tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

How can I set system properties for my project which is running in apache tomcat. I don't wish to add any hard coded properties (like the  or  ).

I am trying to understand what is specified here : [Apache Tomcat Configuration Reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/systemprops.html)

But for my knowledge - I feel some difficulties in understanding it or it is taking too much time.

How can I specify the System Properties in Apache Tomcat 6.0.39

Comment: Can you give us some examples to better understand what do you want to do?

Comment: Like properties-service.xml in JBOSS I need to specify the SystemProperties in Tomcat

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I specify system properties in Tomcat configuration on startup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372686/how-can-i-specify-system-properties-in-tomcat-configuration-on-startup)

Comment: Yes but the answers says to modify the web.xml. But , I need to specify it in the tomcat itself. Like a .sh file or .xml . Is it possible? If so, How?